# Не отображаются элементы css и js на сайте (Bootstrap, python, django)

Tags: python, html, css, django, bootstrap

пишу проект на Python и Django. В html и css знаний особенных не имею, поэтому при выборе шаблона воспользовался Bootstrap, а конкретно его функцией Builder (сконструировал шаблон с теми кнопками, которые мне нужны, а затем скачал архив с js, css, assets и самим файликом html c кодом для всего этого)

Все закинул в папку templates, запускается сайт без элементов css и js ( все фотографии приложу)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно исправить и почему файлы не прогружаются

(структура проекта)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWvT7.png

```
Not Found: /css/heading.css

Not Found: /css/styles.css

[26/Jan/2021 17:28:33] "GET /css/heading.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2408
Not Found: /assets/mail/jqBootstrapValidation.js

[26/Jan/2021 17:28:33] "GET /assets/mail/jqBootstrapValidation.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2471
[26/Jan/2021 17:28:33] "GET /css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2405
Not Found: /css/body.css

[26/Jan/2021 17:28:33] "GET /css/body.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2399
Not Found: /assets/img/avataaars.svg

[26/Jan/2021 17:28:34] "GET /assets/img/avataaars.svg HTTP/1.1" 404 2435
Not Found: /assets/img/portfolio/карт2.jpg
Not Found: /assets/img/portfolio/1151602_3.png

[26/Jan/2021 17:28:34] "GET /assets/img/portfolio/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%822.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2481
[26/Jan/2021 17:28:34] "GET /assets/img/portfolio/1151602_3.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2465
Not Found: /assets/img/portfolio/карт1.jpg

[26/Jan/2021 17:28:34] "GET /assets/img/portfolio/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%821.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2481
Not Found: /assets/mail/jqBootstrapValidation.js
Not Found: /assets/mail/contact_me.js

[26/Jan/2021 17:28:34] "GET /assets/mail/jqBootstrapValidation.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2471
Not Found: /js/scripts.js

[26/Jan/2021 17:28:34] "GET /assets/mail/contact_me.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2438
[26/Jan/2021 17:28:34] "GET /js/scripts.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2402
Not Found: /favicon.ico

[26/Jan/2021 17:28:35] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2396
Not Found: /css/styles.css

[26/Jan/2021 17:40:54] "GET /css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2405
Not Found: /css/heading.css

[26/Jan/2021 17:40:54] "GET /css/heading.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2408
Not Found: /css/body.css

[26/Jan/2021 17:40:54] "GET /css/body.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2399
Not Found: /assets/mail/jqBootstrapValidation.js

[26/Jan/2021 17:40:54] "GET /assets/mail/jqBootstrapValidation.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2471
Not Found: /assets/mail/contact_me.js

[26/Jan/2021 17:40:55] "GET /assets/mail/contact_me.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2438
Not Found: /assets/img/portfolio/карт1.jpg

[26/Jan/2021 17:40:55] "GET /assets/img/portfolio/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%821.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2481
Not Found: /assets/img/portfolio/1151602_3.png
Not Found: /assets/img/portfolio/карт2.jpg

[26/Jan/2021 17:40:55] "GET /assets/img/portfolio/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%822.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2481
Not Found: /js/scripts.js

[26/Jan/2021 17:40:55] "GET /assets/img/portfolio/1151602_3.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2465
Not Found: /assets/img/avataaars.svg

[26/Jan/2021 17:40:55] "GET /js/scripts.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2402
[26/Jan/2021 17:40:55] "GET /assets/img/avataaars.svg HTTP/1.1" 404 2435
Not Found: /assets/mail/jqBootstrapValidation.js

[26/Jan/2021 17:40:57] "GET /assets/mail/jqBootstrapValidation.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2471
Not Found: /assets/mail/contact_me.js

[26/Jan/2021 17:40:57] "GET /assets/mail/contact_me.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2438
Not Found: /js/scripts.js
```

Это ошибки в терминале, то есть не прогружает и не видит ни heading, ни style, ни css и все прочее, хотя все эти файлы есть

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <title>Freelancer - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>
        <!-- Font Awesome icons (free version)-->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/js/all.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Core theme CSS (includes Bootstrap)-->
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Fonts CSS-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/heading.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/body.css">
    </head>
```

(Это начало кода html, где прописал все пути к css)
Bootstrap не скачивал, а если и скачал бы, не знаю, в какую директорию его засунуть, чтобы это исправить

Помогите, пожалуйста :( . Если нужно, дополню еще кодом

Answer (score 1):

это не глобальный проблема.Ми не могу помочь вам потомучто нам / вам надо проверить файлы катурую ви несмогли зделать передачу каторую отображает на странцю. Эта ошибка 404 не найдена(error 404).